# compilation error with yoctoproject with opencv and x11

Tags: linux, opencv, embedded, x11, yocto

I'm developing distribution for raspberry pi 3 using yocto project. I want to make opencv and x11 plugins in this distribution. but I get the following error after "bitbake rpi-avg-image" command. How i can solve this error?

Related part of my local.conf

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " x11"

EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks dev-pkgs tools-sdk tools-profile tools-debug tools-testapps"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3-core python3-pip python3-pandas"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "libopencv-core-dev libopencv-highgui-dev libopencv-imgproc-dev libopencv-objdetect-dev libopencv-ml-dev"
```

Related part of my bblayers.conf

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${YOCTOROOT}/recipes/poky/meta \
  ${YOCTOROOT}/recipes/poky/meta-poky \
  ${YOCTOROOT}/recipes/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  \
  ${YOCTOROOT}/recipes/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${YOCTOROOT}/recipes/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ${YOCTOROOT}/recipes/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  ${YOCTOROOT}/recipes/meta-openembedded/meta-webserver \
  ${YOCTOROOT}/recipes/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  \
  ${YOCTOROOT}/recipes/meta-qt5 \
  \
  ${YOCTOROOT}/recipes/meta-raspberrypi \
  \
  ${YOCTOROOT}/recipes/meta-raspberrypi-avg \
"
```

And i get this error:

```
ERROR: glibc-locale-2.26-r0 do_package: QA Issue: glibc-locale: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /usr/lib/gconv/IBM930.so
  /usr/lib/gconv/CP1258.so

  ...
  ...
  ...

  /usr/share/i18n/charmaps/IBM863.gz
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
glibc-locale: 828 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
ERROR: glibc-locale-2.26-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
ERROR: glibc-locale-2.26-r0 do_package: Function failed: do_package
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/murat/recipes/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc-locale/2.26-r0/temp/log.do_package.6463
ERROR: Task (/home/murat/recipes/poky/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc-locale_2.26.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

With opencv i will processing image and show the pictures on the screen. so I need to add x11 to the distribution I want to obtain.

Thank you from now.

Comment: make sure you're using correct branches; `glibc-locale` is part of `openembedded-core` and unlikely broken.

Comment: also, why do you use `rocko` instead of `sumo`?

Comment: how i can sure i am using glibc-locale?

Comment: 1. make sure you're using `rocko` branch of *every* layer; 2. search for bbappends for glibc-locale.